# jsPdf add word space issue in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, jspdf

I am using jsPDF in Angular project and iterating data from api issue test formatting not working specially word spaces not showing proper.

```
const doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a2");
    const source = document.getElementById("content");

    doc.setFontSize(12)
    doc.html(source, {

      'width': 100,    
      callback: function(pdf) {
        doc.save(userName +'-'+ date);
      } 
    });
```

[image]

solve word space issue and show document in better format

Answer (score 1):

Adding non-zero letter-spacing to CSS seems to fix it.

```
letter-spacing: 0.01px;
```